# Error installing AIR app

Tags: apache-flex, air

I'm unable to install my AIR app now; I think it's because I was uninstalling it and quit halfway thru the uninstall. Here's the error I'm currently seeing:

```
Bootstrapper begin with version 2.6.0.19120 on Win x86  
Installed runtime (3.3.0.3650) located at c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe AIR  
Launching subprocess with commandline "Adobe AIR Application Installer.exe" "C:\Users\a210693\AppData\Local\Temp\AIR7495.tmp\Transporter"  
Application Installer begin with version 3.3.0.3650 on Windows 7 x86  
Commandline is: C:\Users\a210693\AppData\Local\Temp\AIR7495.tmp\Transporter  
Installed runtime (3.3.0.3650) located at c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe AIR  
Validating app in folder C:\Users\a210693\AppData\Local\Temp\AIR7495.tmp\Transporter  
Application signature verified  
Unpackaging/validation complete  
No app located for appID 'transporter' and pubID ''  
Starting app installation to C:\Program Files (x86). Installing app transporter version 0.46 using the source file at file:///C:/Users/a210693/AppData/Local/Temp/AIR7495.tmp/Transporter  
Installing msi at C:\Users\a210693\AppData\Local\Temp\AIR7495.tmp\Transporter\setup.msi with guid {0ABBADCF-B729-C4A4-8D6E-2D2954077F1F}  

**Error occurred during msi install operation; beginning rollback:** [ErrorEvent type="error" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="1603" errorID=0]  
Rolling back install of C:\Users\a210693\AppData\Local\Temp\AIR7495.tmp\Transporter\setup.msi  
Rollback complete  
**Got an unexpected fatal error while in stateInstalling:** [ErrorEvent type="error" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="1603" errorID=0]  
Launching subprocess with commandline c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe AIR\Versions\1.0\Adobe AIR Application Installer -runtime "c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files" -silent -logToStdout -url -location "C:\Program Files (x86)" -desktopShortcut -programMenu file:///C:/Users/a210693/AppData/Local/Temp/AIR7495.tmp/Transporter  
Relaunching with elevation  


Application Installer begin with version 3.3.0.3650 on Windows 7 x86  
Commandline is: -stdio \\.\pipe\AIR_4588_0 -runtime "c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files" -silent -logToStdout -url -location "C:\Program Files (x86)" -desktopShortcut -programMenu file:///C:/Users/a210693/AppData/Local/Temp/AIR7495.tmp/Transporter  
Installed runtime (3.3.0.3650) located at c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe AIR
Validating app in folder C:\Users\a210693\AppData\Local\Temp\AIR7495.tmp\Transporter  
Application signature verified  
Unpackaging/validation complete  
No app located for appID 'transporter' and pubID ''  
Starting silent app installation to C:\Program Files (x86). Installing app transporter version 0.46 using the source file at file:///C:/Users/a210693/AppData/Local/Temp/AIR7495.tmp/Transporter  
Installing msi at C:\Users\a210693\AppData\Local\Temp\AIR7495.tmp\Transporter\setup.msi with guid {0ABBADCF-B729-C4A4-8D6E-2D2954077F1F}  
Error occurred during msi install operation; beginning rollback: [ErrorEvent type="error" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="1603" errorID=0]  
Rolling back install of C:\Users\a210693\AppData\Local\Temp\AIR7495.tmp\Transporter\setup.msi  
Rollback complete  
Got an unexpected fatal error while in stateInstalling: [ErrorEvent type="error" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="1603" errorID=0]  
Elevated install failed: error 0 1603  
Application Installer end with exit code 7  
Subprocess Application Installer failed (7)  
Bootstrapper end with exit code 7
```

I've gone through and deleted the directories for my AIR app, including a directory in the appDate local store. I'm using Windows 7 on a 64 bit machine.

I don't want to re-image my computer. Any helpful ideas would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you posting?  Is that a log file?  Or an error message you see?  Or something else?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I tried formatting it as best I could. It is a log file. It's the AIR error log, Install.log.

Comment: I've bolded the text that pinpoints the error detail.

Comment: Sorry, I've reformatted your log to be more readable (hopefully) in a code block. Your asterisked log messages though are still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use Microsoft Cleanup to remove/uninstall Adobe AIR here: http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall/en-us
2. Download the latest version of Adobe AIR here: http://get.adobe.com/air/