# An error occurred while installing Adobe AIR

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air, adobe, salesforce

- I'm trying many time to install Adobe AIR.
  Normal : Error said...

> **An error occurred while installing Adobe AIR. Installation may not be allowed by your administrator. Please contact your administrator.**

Then, I run as Administrator, but I get same error message...

- I download installer again, but there is same error message...
- I install with same installer in another laptop, but I get same error message...

I'm on Win XP SP3 professional edition.(another laptop : XP SP3 home edition)

Download AIR [Link](http://get.adobe.com/air/otherversions/)

This is log... There is no command line??

> [2012-07-16:14:23:25] Runtime Installer begin with version 3.3.0.3670 on Windows XP x86
>   
> [2012-07-16:14:23:25] **Commandline is:**
>   
> [2012-07-16:14:23:25] No installed runtime detected
>   
> [2012-07-16:14:23:28] Starting runtime install. Installing runtime version 3.3.0.3670
>   
> [2012-07-16:14:23:28] Installing msi at c:\docume~1\admini~1\locals~1\temp\air1fb.tmp\setup.msi with guid {65CB4C08-C47B-4A7E-A6A4-50C06ADA5FC6}
>   
> [2012-07-16:14:23:28] Error occurred during msi install operation; beginning rollback: [ErrorEvent type="error" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="1601" errorID=0]
>   
> [2012-07-16:14:23:28] Rolling back install of c:\docume~1\admini~1\locals~1\temp\air1fb.tmp\setup.msi
>   
> [2012-07-16:14:23:28] Rollback complete
>   
> [2012-07-16:14:23:28] Exiting due to error: [ErrorEvent type="error" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="1601" errorID=0]
>   
> [2012-07-16:14:23:30] Runtime Installer end with exit code 7

This is relate [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416258/error-installing-air-app), but there is no point too.

---

**[-Solved-]**
**Solution**:  To check whether the Windows Installer service is set to a value of Disable
Click Start, type services.msc in the start search box and press enter.
In the Services (Local) list, right-click Windows Installer, and then click Properties.
If the Startup type drop-down list is set to a value of Disable, select the Manual option from the Startup type drop-down list.
Click on Start button below the heading service status and click OK.
Then try to install again...

Credit: [Microsoft](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/error-1601-windows-installer-is-not-accessible/08dce679-496d-43f4-a4b5-bb467800bb90)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be related to Windows Installer service.

Here is the similar problem report: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/42878

Try recommendations from here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/error-1601-windows-installer-is-not-accessible/08dce679-496d-43f4-a4b5-bb467800bb90

Comment: Very surprise! I have to search many forum in adobe for many day ago... but I have not found. I try in your link on microsoft, it said about "**Windows installer**". It is fix.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

None of the solutions worked for me.  Looking in the install log I found errors 1603 and 1605 coming up every time I tried to install the latest update to Adobe Air.  I had had no issues with this for several years since the 1.x series yet on the latest version 14.x version the troubles began.  The fix was to use the **Windows Installer Cleanup Utility** which Microsoft no longer makes available but thankfully MajorGeeks.com and Softpedia.com have it in their archives.  It was only designed for XP and maybe Vista.  So if you have a newer version of Windows look for solutions elsewhere unless you are looking for problems.  Anyway long story short I deleted the entry for Adobe Air and suddenly all my install problems were over.

Comment: I had the same problem on Windows 7. Got error 1603 when trying to upgrade or uninstall. The solution for me was the Windows Fix-It utility for install issues [Program Install and Uninstall troubleshooter](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301) I uninstalled AIR version 3.1 using this M$ utility and was able to install version 15 afterward.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue and my Windows Installer service was set to manual, but it wasn't started. I clicked Start button and after that I was able to install Adobe AIR.